# Finding Vector components given vector equation

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations

I am self studying linear algebra via the book "No BS Guide to Linear Algebra" and there is this exercise in the book (E2.3).

[image]

The chapter containing this problem didn't have any examples of problems like this, it's main focus was on some matrix-vector properties such as the inverse matrix and how it interacts with the matrix-vector product.

Totally at a loss as to what to even search on google to point me in the right direction on this one.

Don't need a blatant answer to this exact problem, but some direction would be fantastic.

Comment: Hint: $Ev$ is a linear combination of columns of $E.$

Comment: $Ev = v_1 e_1 + v_2 e_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: this is really just testing your understanding of how matrix multiplication works:
$$\pmatrix{a&c\cr b&d\cr}\pmatrix{v_1\cr v_2\cr}
  =\pmatrix{av_1+cv_2\cr bv_1+dv_2\cr}
  =v_1\pmatrix{a\cr b\cr}+v_2\pmatrix{c\cr d\cr}\ .$$